# Can the calcification response of a marine organisms, at different pH conditions, be assessed by the calcium magnesium ratio?

Tags: marine-biology, calcium

Can the calcification response of a marine organisms, at different pH conditions, be assessed by the calcium magnesium ratio?
the calcium magnesium ratio is a proxy  of calcification?